# Should I replace existing 4x4 posts?

Tags: repair

[image]I currently have a high 20x14 deck attached to the back of my house on a very sloped yard. It is 13 ft off the ground and in great shape. However, It is currently supported by 4x4 posts that are in the ground(don't know if they are attached to concrete footings or not) and notched at the top where it is attached to a 2x8 and 2x10 ledger support.

We want to eventually close in half of the deck and make it a 3-seasons room. Should I replace these 4x4 posts with 6x6 posts(due to added weight of 3 seasons room)? Or could I just add the 6x6 posts directly right next to the existing 4x4 posts, so I don't have to jack up deck/remove 4x4s? I would dig new holes for the 6x6 posts, with poured concrete and use post base to attach them above ground and use post caps to attach to the existing support ledgers.

I am looking for the safest, most efficient way a DIYer can achieve this herself. We are located in Georgia, so we really don't get snow, but we do get a little ice here and there.

**BTW** One of the posts is shredding at the ground level and the corner posts looks like it is cracking.

[image]

Comment: I'm having a hard time knowing what I'm seeing in that extreme closeup. Maybe back out a bit and show a couple angles.

Comment: I'm sure you'll have this conversation with the building inspection/permits people, but I'd be concerned about how appropriate the floor structure is for your 3 season room plan.

Answer (score 2):

**Deck**

If the 4x4 posts were up to code for when the deck was built then your proposal would be considered a repair and repairs usually have looser guidelines.

Yes, adding 6x6 posts next to the 4x4 posts would be a huge safety improvement and likely exceeds current code so that's super!

Your main consideration is whether you are okay with the look of doubled up posts. If not then jack up the deck and do a replacement. If you're okay with the look then follow through with your plan since it sounds like a huge improvement.

**Sunroom**

I do not know if deck conversion into sunroom has additional code implications that your current deck does not meet.

I would check the code requirements for a sunroom before proceeding with your 6x6 idea because it would be a shame to do the 6x6 posts and later find out that the sunroom must be built from scratch due to deficiencies with the deck.

Comment: The only caveat is the OP's point that the 4x4s are starting to fail. Yes, new 6x6 sistered up to them will take the load should one fail (and will probably prevent the failure of the cracked one, while the rotting one will continue to rot). In that case, replacement seems to make more sense and avoids the (potentially ugly) double-post look.

Comment: I honestly don't mind the look of the double posts, because I know how to strategically place plants, decor to make it look great...lol. I am waiting on the senior inspector to contact me back with his recommendations. thanks for your answers.

Comment: The legal question is whether adding a 3-season room is a simple modification or major renovation.  Only the building department can answer this.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore Yes, I addressed that in my answer. I bolded a few things to make the distinction more prominent. It sounds like OP is working with the town to legally build this sunroom.

Comment: @FreeMan OP commented on the double-post look. It's a free country! =)

Comment: @TerriLScott if you're happy with the double-post look, then by all means go with it. Do be aware, though, that since you mentioned that one of the 4x4s was "shredding" (I presume that's your term for what you see as it rots), it will continue to rot, even with a 6x6 next to it. If that 4x4 is wicking water up from the ground, the parts that remain in contact with the ground and the 6x6 _could_ transfer water to the new post and cause premature damage to it. Something to consider.

Comment: @FreeMan OP did mention new holes and concrete for the 6x6 posts so presumably this means they'll be far enough away from the old ones.

Comment: Yes, the 6x6s will be next to the 4x4 post on both sides, but not attached to it. I honestly don't care if I have a WALL of 6x6s...as long as it is safe and up to code and sufficient for a 3 seasons room.

Comment: And yes, I am working with the city and inspectors to do everything correctly. Hopefully, I won't have to tear down the existing deck and could just do some minor renovations to bring it up to code.

Answer (score 0):

YES YES YES!

You should do this even if you are not going to enclose the area. This deck is not to current code.  I suggest you consult a professional, as you have no idea what other deficiencies there are.

See Page 7 of  [Georgia Deck Code Amendments](https://www.alpharetta.ga.us/docs/default-source/community-dev/buildings-inspections/deck-manual.pdf?sfvrsn=cdb6f4ab_10)

> Deck posts shall be 6x6 with a maximum height of 14'-0" measured from
> the top of the footing to the underside of the beam.

EDIT: Comments say that original deck was built under permit and was constructed to code at the time, and is grandfathered in.  However, the building department may require it to be brought up to code as part of a major renovation.  I suggest consulting an engineer on this build - it's money well spent.  13 feet is a long way to fall and could be potentially fatal.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. For clarification, take them down and replace them or just add the 6x6s next to them? The inspector was out and said it was up to code for when it was built.

Comment: Well, the inspector knows best.  Did you pull a permit for the 3-season room?   They may consider it a major renovation and require you to bring it up to code.  Also, do you know if the original deck was built under permit?  If it was, you can usually for a reasonable fee,  have the inspectors office pull the file containing the original application and plans - It might help you answer a few questions about the current construction.

Comment: No, we haven't pulled the permit for the 3 seasons room yet. We are just trying to make sure everything is up to code 1st, before moving forward. The existing deck was built under permit. I will contact the permits office to get the plans. Thanks again!

Comment: My son's former house had a sun room (heated & air conditioned, so 4 seasons) built over an existing deck.  The deck was supported away from the house with 4x4 posts (3 or 4) on which the beam rested.  This was permitted and inspected in anal retentive Howard County, MD.  One difference from your situation is that his maximum post height was 8', and some of the posts were only 4" tall (built over a hill).

Comment: I'm finding max height for a 4x4 tops out at 10 feet according to current codes.  The issue is not strength in vertical compression, but buckling. That is, bowing out in the middle like )